# Git ignores modified files if it has been deleted

Tags: git

I just had a case where `git` decided to automagically delete a file, although in my opinion it shouldn't have done so.

Here's the scenario:

I have a file `foo`. I start a new branch off of `master` – named `feature`. In `feature` I delete the file `foo`. `master` is evolving and I constantly rebase `feature` on top of `master`. At some point the `foo` file is being updated on `master`. Now I just tried rebasing onto `master` again, and `git` silently ignored the changes to `foo`, instead of giving me a merge conflict.

Is there any way to prevent that behavior during a rebase or is `git` designed to behave this way? Or is it due to my constant rebasing, so the common base between `master` and `feature` didn't have `foo` anymore and `git` decides to ignore all the changes from the `master` branch?

Comment: Since you have deleted the file. I think git assumed that you want to remove the file foo. So when you rebased the file deleted in your feature branch got deleted when it was rebased in branch.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your observed behavior. If you have a [mcve], please include it.